# MediaWiki plural links

Tags: links, mediawiki

I have quite a lot of pages with plural named titles, eg **widgets**.

If a mention a widget and want to make it a link I have to put **[[widgets|widget]]**.

I know there is a pipe trick to give a singular title a plural link: **[[widget]]s**

Is there a similar shortcut to make a plural title singular?

<sub>Not a major deal, I just seem to be doing it a lot and I would hate to think I am missing an obvious trick somewhere.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

No. If you really want you can write a template that containes something like `[[{{{1}}}s|{{{1}}}]]` and is called like `{{p|widget}}`. Probably does way more problems than worth it though. Or you can make a redirect from `widget` to `widgets`.

(FWIW the [pipe trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Pipe_trick) and the [link trail](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Linktrail) are different things.)